# unable to install scrapy-deltafetch

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to install scrapy-deltafetch on ubuntu 14 using pip (v8.1.2 on python 2.7).  When I run (sudo) pip install scrapy-deltafetch, I get the following error:

**Update:**

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Can't find a local Berkeley DB installation.
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-TVr3UZ/bsddb3/
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

I have already ran the following:

```
sudo python ez_setup.py

pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

as well as

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

I do have both python3 and python 2.7 on the computer.

I have tried installing bsdb3 but that does not work either.  I will look into setting up berkeley db correctly and update here accordingly

**Update**:
Installing berkeley DB did not solve the issue.

Comment: Is that all of the log? Also have you tried spawning a fresh virtual env and installing it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrapy-deltafetch requires `bsddb3`.

`bsddb3` itself, on Ubuntu Trusty, [depends on `libdb5.3`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/trusty/python-bsddb3).

You can either install `python-bsddb3` with `apt-get`, or only `apt-get install libdb5.3`. `pip install scrapy-deltafetch` should work after that.

Comment: worked after I installed python-bsddb3 (installed libdb5. as well)

Answer (score 1):

Install libbd-dev first,

```
sudo apt-get install libdb-dev
```

then install deltafetch,

```
# for python2
sudo -H pip install scrapy-deltafetch
# for python3
sudo -H pip3 install scrapy-deltafetch
```

Comment: thanks for sharing- i was able to get it to work after installing python-bsddb3